# Value of $a+b+10$ in differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin\lfloor x^2\rfloor \pi}{x^2-3x+8}+ax^3+b,& 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
> 2\cos(\pi x)+\tan^{-1}(x), & 1<x\leq 2
> \end{cases}$$
> is differentiable on $[0,2]$. Then value of $a+b+10$

What i Try:: Here function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=1$ means function is continuous at $x=1$.

So
$$f(1)=\begin{cases}
0+a+b, & 0\leq x\leq 1\\
-2+\frac{\pi}{4}, & 1<x\leq 2
\end{cases}$$

So for continuity at $x=1,$ We have $a+b=\frac{\pi}{4}-2\Longrightarrow a+b+10=8+\frac{\pi}{4}$

Please tell me is my process is right or wrong because answer given as $11.14$

Comment: Do you know how to write and how to use left-sided limit and right-sided limit? Those are what you should be using for this problem.

Comment: It looks like the book did $8+\pi$ instead